# I cannot show images which is url type

Tags: python, html, django

I cannot show images which is  url type.
I wrote in product.html

```
<body>
{% for product in products.all %}
    <h4> {{ product.product_title }}</h4>
    <img src="{% static product.image }} %}"/>
    <p> {{ product.body }} </p>

{% endfor %}
</body>
```

in models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    image = models.TextField()
    body = models.TextField()
```

in views.py

```
def product(request):
    products = Product.objects.order_by('product_title')
    return render(request, 'registration/product.html',{'products':products})
```

From admin site,I added product_title&image&body.
image's urls is

```
<a href="https://xxxxxx" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">
<img border="0" width="120" height="60" alt="" src="https://wwwyyyyyyyyyyyy"></a>
<img border="0" width="1" height="1" src="https://wwwzzzzzzzzzz" alt="">
```

By using Google console,Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) is in Console.
In Elements,img tag is like

```
<img src="/static/wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww">
```

How can I show image?Am I wrong to write the way of img tag & src?

Comment: Uploaded images are not static files.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I cannot understand what u r saying.Could u tell me more in detail?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use pictures in Django, you have to configure your application like this :

**First step : Static and Media**

In your `settings.py` file, write something like this :

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")]

PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static/')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join('path_to_your_Media_directory')
```

**Second step : Implement Image field in your model**

In your models.py file :

```
Image = models.ImageField(upload_to='upload_file_directory', null=True, blank=True, width_field=None, height_field=None, default=" ")
```

**Third step : Handle image in your view**

In your views.py file (don't forget `request.FILES or None` !) :

```
if request.method == 'POST':

        form = 'YourForm'(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)

        if form.is_valid() :
            post = form.save()
```

And in your template, don't forget `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form class

**Fourth step : Call your image in your template**

```
{% if 'your_image_exist' %}
   <img src='{{Model.Image.url}}' height="300" width="400"/>
{% endif %}
```

It's a global example, but you have to set all these things in order to handle picture with Django !
Good luck

Comment: thx ur answer.You wrote  Image = models.ImageField(upload_to='upload_file_directory', null=True, blank=True, width_field=None, height_field=None, default=" ") , I cannot understand how to write upload_to='upload_file_directory' because I update images from Django admin site.

Comment: In my Media directory, I have some directories : `pictures`, `maps`, ... If you have configured correctly your `Media` in settings.py, you just have to write : `upload_to='pictures/'` if you want to make reference to pictures directory inside Media ;)

This way lets to upload images and store these images where do you want.

Answer (score 1):

Your image is not a static file. Since its a textfield and its content is a url you just have put the value in the src attribute. There is no need of using the static tag.

Try this:

```
 <img src="{{ product.image }}"/>
```

Comment: Might need to use the `|safe` filter there.

Comment: thx,ur answer.I wrote ur codes,but no image is shown.By using Google console,[Deprecation] Resource requests whose URLs contained both removed whitespace (`\n`, `\r`, `\t`) characters and less-than characters (`<`) are blocked. Please remove newlines and encode less-than characters from places like element attribute values in order to load these resources. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5735596811091968 for more details.   is shown.What does it happen in my web site?

Comment: Looks like `product.image` might contain an invalid url. What is the content of the field? Does it contain a html tag, and not just the image url?